# PHP Include Not Working from Another File

Tags: php

My file structure:

- sys : **a folder containing 3 sub folders**: *inc*, *class*, and *config*. The *inc* folder has a `php` file `init.php`.
- `index.php` **in the root folder**.

My *config* folder has a file with the **DB** credentials which is `include_once ('..\config\db_credentials.php');` in `init.php`. The init file is working fine with included file.

I have also included `include_once ('sys\inc\init.inc.php');` in `index.php` but if I run the index file it says:

*Warning: include_once(..\config\db_credentials.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\wamp\www\example\sys\inc\init.inc.php on line 3*

and

*Warning: include_once(): Failed opening '..\config\db_credentials.php' for inclusion (include_path='.;C:\php\pear') in C:\wamp\www\example\sys\inc\init.inc.php on line 3*

What am I doing wrong and how can I make this work?

Comment: can you please provide file/folder with a tree structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you set [include path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-include-path.php) to the location of your files to be included, and use [namespaces](http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.php) to separate between them.

Relative locations of your files are bad, such as `../foo.php`, but using relative location based on include path (`config/dbconfig.php`) and only that you would not get any more surprises. This would result in a more robust configuration.

Answer (score 4):

use slashes instead of backslashes

```
include_once ('../config/db_credentials.php');.
```

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the file you're including is relative to the current document.

Or as I would do it:

Use the `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` as a prefix everywhere (or `define('DOCROOT', $path);` in the config/index)

Answer (score 0):

In your init file you have to put `include_once ('config/db_credentials.php');`.

Becausewhen you have cascading includes, the root directory is always the first called file. Here it's your `index.php` file ; so all includes have to be from here.

Your current include will work if your directly launch the init.php file. That's one of the cons against includes ; namespaces are better for that :)

Answer (score -2):

You can include file via **file** php built in function.

first echo **file**; in which file u want to include.

use dirname(**file**); to out form one directory.

when u come on your desire directory then include like

include( dirname(**file**).'/file.php' );

Note: **file** function return u absolute path of your file.

may be its helpful for u.